# IPython notebook doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I tried to run IPython notebook. I entered following in the commandline:

ipython notebook

I get the following error (stack trace)

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 9, in <module>
>     load_entry_point('ipython==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py",
> line 388, in launch_new_instance
>     app.initialize()   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 84, i n catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py",
> line 313, in initialize
>     super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 84, i n catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 325,
> in  initialize
>     self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\terminal\ipapp.py",
> line 308, in parse_command_line
>     return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 84, i n catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 420, in parse_command_line
>     return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 84, i n catch_config_error
>     return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py", line
> 352, in initialize_subcommand
>     subapp = import_item(subapp)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py", line
> 40, i n import_item
>     module = __import__(package,fromlist=[obj])   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\html\notebook\__init__.py
> ", line 8, in <module>
>     raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: The IPython Notebook requires tornado >= 2.1.0
```

how do I fix this? 
I have Python version 2.7

Comment: The IPython Notebook requires tornado >= 2.1.0

Comment: I assume you have windows os.Have you followed these [installation steps in Windows](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#windows)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to install the tornado webserver. Assuming you have pip installed and on your path:

> pip install tornado

Comment: See here for installing pip on windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: download tornado installer from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tornado), then double-click.

Comment: you'll need to open the visual studio command prompt OR run the vcvarsall.bat (in your visual studio folders) OR manually set the ncessary environment variables. Once you've done that, run pip.

Comment: pip install tornado --upgrade

Comment: If you are on linux, and you already have the python-tornado package of your distribution installed, also do this:`sudo apt-get remove python-tornado`.

Comment: This doesn't help on windows. Subcommand `ipython notebook` is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.